# Вывод double с нужной точностью и в нужном формате

Tags: c++, строки, stl, double, format

Требуется вывести `double` с максимальной точностью, при этом целую часть, которая не превышает 999 вывести с пробелами на месте отсутствующих цифр, типа `9,12...`

Вывожу следующим образом

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1) << value << std::endl;
```

Возникло 2 проблемы:

1) везде читал, что точность `double` определяется как `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`, однако похоже, что можно вытащить больше значащих цифр, если задать точность в 20 цифр, то будут видны все 20 отличных от 0 цифр

2) не нашел, как можно задать размер целой части, чтобы заполнить отсутствующие цифры пробелами

Подскажите, что требуется сделать?

Comment: double содержит 15-16 значащих цифр (52 двоичных разряда мантиссы), больше смысла не имеет

Comment: Чтобы выводить пробелы в старших позициях, используйте функции с классическим форматированием, такие как `snprintf`. В STL возможности форматирования довольно убогие, с ними мало что можно сделать.

Comment: @MBo, но почему когда я задаю более длинную запись, то внутри нее так же значащие цифры есть, а не 0? Или это просто случайный набор цифр.

Comment: @frem, это действительно так, но очень уж хотелось сделать все в едином стиле, а так придётся создавать отдельные переменные, потом уже их выводить

Comment: Зачем отдельные переменные создавать? `printf` все выведет точно так же, без всяких переменных. Отвечу за @MBo: 2^52 это 4.5*10^15, вот вам все, что можно представить в 52 битах, т.е. чуть больше 15 цифр. Ваши 20 цифр либо мусор, либо чудо, либо новая математика.

Comment: @freim, это не чудо, а просто мусор

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, я тоже догадался :)

Comment: Запустил программу: `double pi = 3.1415926; printf("%35.30f", pi);`, она напечатала `3.141592600000000068405370257096`. Воистину чудо, ага. Зато сразу видно где кончаются значащие цифры.

Comment: @freim, да,  В STL возможности форматирования довольно убогие, но всегда можно написать свой манипулятор(не трудно), если ты этим часто пользоваться будешь...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, это если только для фанатов STL, а так какой смысл? Стандартный формат хорошо отлажен, предоставляет все мыслимые возможности, проще и  нагляднее, чем громоздить цепочки манипуляторов. Самая спорная возможность STL, по-моему.

Comment: @freim, да, я согласен, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Величина `digits10` еще имеет какой-то смысл для целой части плавающего числа. Для дробной части она бессмысленна. Даже обычный `float` может потребовать сотен знаков после запятой в точном строковом представлении.

Comment: @freim: Не существует никакого способа выразить ограничения на плавающую часть *двоичного* плавающего типа в *десятичных* цифрах. Ни о каких "15 цифр" не может быть и речи - это бессмыслица и профанация. Никакого "чуда", "мусора" или "новой математики" там нет. А есть просто следующее абсолютно точно представимое значение. Обычный плавающий тип может представлять точно десятичные значения с *сотнями* десятичных цифр после запятой. Просто эти точно представимые значения, условно выражаясь, "далеко" отстоят друг от друга.

Comment: @freim: Вычисляем `std::pow(2, -100);`, распечатываем, видим 70 десятичных цифр. Все эти 70 десятичных цифр - *абсолютно идеально гарантированно точны*. Все до единой. Вы же нам рассказываете какие-то сказки про "чуть больше 15 цифр", "мусор" и "новую математику".

Comment: @AnT, да, конечно. Часы, которые стоят, два раза в сутки показывают абсолютно точное время, и из этого можно сделать вывод, что они по точности не уступают атомному эталону. Этот рассказ про бесконечную точность double примерно из той же серии.

Comment: @freim: Ну, здрасьте! С такой точки зрения любой тип данных фиксированного размера - "сломанные часы, которые  два раза в сутки показывают абсолютно точное время". Возможности внутренних представлений надо знать и понимать досконально - только так можно научиться ими правильно пользоваться. А "15-16 цифр" - это оставьте студентам-первокурсникам.

Comment: @AnT, золотые слова насчет того, что надо знать возможности внутренних представлений. Хорошо, что вы это поняли, изучайте. Если мы представляем мантиссу двумя десятичными цифрами, существует ровно 100 вещественных чисел, которые она передает абсолютно точно. Но это не значит, что у нее точность бесконечная, она по прежнему всего лишь две цифры. Мантисса double представляет точно 2^52 числа, но точность ее от этого опять же не становится бесконечной. Это те же 52 двоичных или примерно 16 десятичных цифр. В общем, хватит уже глупостей - если хочется потроллить, идите в политоту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё, чего вам не хватало, это задать заполнитель `setfill` и ширину `setw` выводимого поля:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

void print(double value)
{
    const auto digits = std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10;
    std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(digits + 4);
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(digits) << value << std::endl;    
}

int main()
{
    double value = 9.12;
    print(value);
}
```

[Результат выполнения](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CuyeZJvWgs4RjwIJ)

Comment: Эти три строки, от которых глаза выпадают, полностью заменяются одним вызовом `printf("%20.16f", value);`.

Comment: @freim если точнее то аналогом будет `printf("%20.*f", DBL_DIG, value)` и да, нормальный питоно-подобный `format` [есть в boost'е](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/format/doc/format.html)...

Comment: std::setfill(' ') это лишнее, поскольку по умолчанию пробелами и заполняется...

Answer (score 4):

Можно также написать  класс, с функциональностью выводить как угодно. Например:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class  IM {
    double d;
    size_t ww;
    char c;
public:
    IM(double val, size_t whole_size, char imbue = ' ')
        : d(val), ww(whole_size), c(imbue) {}
    int get_whole() const
    {
        return d;
    }
    int get_fraction() const
    {
        stringstream s;
        s << d - get_whole();
        int k;
        s.ignore(2); // пропускаем '0' и '.'
        s >> k;
        return k;
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const IM& m)
    {
        os << setw(m.ww) << setiosflags(ios_base::left) <<setfill(m.c)
           << m.get_whole() << '.' << m.get_fraction();
        return os;
    }
};
```

И пример программы:

```
double d = 2.45;
IM dd(d, 10, '5');
cout << dd << endl << dd.get_whole() << endl << dd.get_fraction();
/* вывод:
   2555555555.45
   2
   45
*/
```

Можно и манипулятор написать, но такой класс, думаю, более полезен в том смысле, что может выдавать целую и дробную части

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, смысл величины `digits10` для плавающего типа `T` заключается в том, что если вы возьмете десятичное строковое представление, преобразуете его в значение типа `T`, а затем преобразуете его из `T` обратно в десятичное строковое представление, то вы получите `digits10` значащих цифр цифр, совпадающих с вашей исходной строкой. Например, если вы используете плавающий тип для хранения целых значений, то целые значения с таким количеством цифр будут представляться без потерь, как и соседние (+-1) целые значения.

Родственной величиной является величина `max_digits10`, которая говорит, что если вы преобразуете плавающее значение типа `T` в десятичное строковое представление с сохранением `max_digits10` старших значащих цифр, а затем преобразуете его обратно в тип `T`, то вы гарантированно получите исходное значение типа `T`.

Таким образом, величина `digits10` описывает сохранение данных в преобразовании туда-обратно вида "строка<sub>10</sub> -> плавающее -> строка<sub>10</sub>". А величина `max_digits10` описывает сохранение данных в преобразовании туда-обратно вида "плавающее -> строка<sub>10</sub>  -> плавающее".

Это, однако, совсем не означает, что десятичное строковое плавающее значение будет иметь только столько точных цифр. Огульно обзывать цифры за пределами этого количества "мусором" - очевидная профанация. Какие цифры являются точными, а какие нет - определяется спецификой ваших вычислений и известно только вам.

Очевидный пример: "традиционные" двоичные плавающие типы способны точно представлять степени двойки в пределах возможностей экспоненты. То есть `std::pow(2, 512)` даст вам точное значение типа `double`

```
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096
```

в котором намного больше значащих цифр, чем `digits10` или `max_digits10` для `double` (`15` и `17` соответственно). Никакого "мусора" в этом представлении нет (разумеется, если вы хотели вычислить именно 2<sup>512</sup>) . Вас это не должно удивлять. Умение пользоваться такими возможностями плавающих представлений - это во многом и есть умение пользоваться плавающими типами в общем.

Во-вторых, что касается управления шириной поля при выводе - об этом вы уже получили ответы.

Answer (score 2):

По ходу обсуждения оказалось, что имеет смысл остановиться подробнее на определении точности вещественного типа. Удивительно, но оказывается, что точность `double` совсем не жалкие 15 цифр, а намного, намного больше! И в подтверждение приводятся числа 2^(-100) и 2^512, которые действительно представляются точно. Так что же, получается что и в самом деле точность `double` больше, чем 15 цифр? К сожалению нет, такие заявления говорят лишь о непонимании вещественной арифметики.

Давайте посмотрим на представление чисел вещественным типом. Точность представления определяется его мантиссой, которая в случае числа двойной точности имеет длину 52 бита и соответственно может представить 2^52 значений. Теперь возьмем некое число, у которого в двоичном представлении биты мантиссы 53, 54, и т.д. являются нулями. Нетрудно видеть, что такое число будет представлено абсолютно точно. С бесконечной точностью! И таких чисел существует ровно 2^52.

Попробуем теперь немного уменьшить требования к точности. Возьмем, скажем, тысячу знаков после запятой - есть ли числа, которые представляются с такой точностью? Да, такие числа в самом деле есть, и из свойств множества действительных чисел видно, что их бесконечно много. Какую бы точность мы ни задали - сто, тысячу, миллион знаков после запятой, - оказывается, что существует бесконечно много чисел, представимых именно с такой точностью.

Получается, что точность вещественного типа это какая-то странная характеристика, которая произвольно меняется в зависимости от числа вплоть до бесконечности? Нет, именно в этом месте и происходит путаница! Точность представления отдельно взятого числа не имеет никакого отношения к точности вещественного типа. Слово одно, но под ним подразумеваются совершенно разные вещи. А собственно точность представления числа, хотя и кажется очень важной с бытовой точки зрения, в вещественной арифметике никакого значения не имеет. По той простой причине, что она непредсказуема - мы не можем определить точность представления по результату вычислений. Для этого надо этот результат сравнить с эталонным значением, а если мы и так его знаем, то зачем нам что-то вычислять?

Так что же такое точность вещественного типа? Представим, что у нас есть два числа, у которых первые 52 бита мантиссы совпадают, а различается бит 53. Эти два числа будут представлены одной и той же мантиссой, и соответственно, тем же самым числом двойной точности. Мы говорим, что точность `double` составляет 52 бита, и это означает простую вещь: `double` различает только числа, у которых отличаются первые 52 бита. Числа, у которых отличаются только биты 53 и последующие, представляются одной и той же мантиссой. Вот это и есть точность! Соответственно,в десятичном виде точность `double` составляет 15.45 десятичных цифр. Это означает, что числа, отличающиеся первыми 15 знаками всегда представляются разными значениями `double`. Числа с отличиями в 16-ом знаке могут представляться разными значениями (в 45% случаев), а могут и не отличаться (соответственно, в 55% случаев). Числа с отличием в 17-ом и более младших знаках имеют одинаковое представление в числе двойной точности.

Разумеется, тема точности вещественной арифметики немного сложнее этого простого определения. Для более серьезного ознакомления можно посоветовать Д. Кнут, том 2 "*Получисленные алгоритмы*", глава 4.2.2 "*Точность выполнения арифметических действий в системе с плавающей точкой*".